# Horizontal menu hover out delay CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, css, delay, mousehover

I'm trying to make dropdown menu with a delay on mouse over. My menu is very deep and sometimes when you are eg in 3rd level and you miss the dropdowns it will disappear all.
I know that I can use  `opacity:0` and `transition: 0.5s 2s;` but I can't figure out for which elements in my particular example to use it.

```html
<li class="parent" id="hcategory_823">
  <h3>
    <a href="/kuchnia" title="Kuchnia" id="headlink43" class="spanhover mainlevel">
      <span>Kuchnia</span>

    </a>
  </h3>
  <div class="submenu level1">
    <ul class="level1">
      <li class="parent" id="hcategory_1697">
        <p class="zah3">
          <a href="/kuchnia/nowoczesna" title="Kuchnia nowoczesna" id="headercategory1697" class="spanhover">
            <span>Kuchnia nowoczesna</span>

          </a>
        </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

This is the example code for one level.
So I want to "Kuchnia nowoczesna" appear after "Kuchnia" mouse hover, stay visible if cursor is on "Kuchnia nowoczesna" and disappear after 1s if cursor leave the "Kuchnia nowoczesna" area.

Comment: transition and animation can have a delay `animation-delay: x` or `transition-delay: x` .if set on the element and not only on :hover, it works for both mousehover & mouseout. share your code if you really need help ;)

Comment: Ok, example code in main post.

Comment: i turn your code into a snippet , feel free to edit again to demonstrate your issue ;)

Comment: done, this is explenation for very first level, but If I will resolve this, maybe I will figure out next levels.